# push firebase data inside an array + js + vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vuejs2, google-cloud-firestore

I have in `firebase firestore` a Collection named *users* created with docs of unique id.

Now I would like to push them in an `Array`.

(In the usersCollection there are 3 users stored with the `currentUser.uid`)

Example:

```
fb.usersCollection.where("state", "==", 'online').get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
         const userName = doc.data().name

  this.markerMy = { name: userName }
})

// push userName inside randomArray
const randomArray = []
randomArray.push(this.markerMy)
```

I only get it so that I can push one user inside the Array, but not more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should declare `randomArray` before `fb.usersCollection` and call the push operation inside the callback as follows :

```
const randomArray = []
fb.usersCollection.where("state", "==", 'online').get().then(querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
        const userName = doc.data().name

        this.markerMy = {
          name: userName
        }

        randomArray.push(this.markerMy)
      })
   });
```